# mootools | Unique email verification

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, mootools

I have a mootools script:

```
Form.Validator.add('UniqueEmail', {
   errorMsg: 'Email is taken',
   test: function(element, props) {

      var valid = false;
      if (element.value.length > 0) {

         site.request(app, {'action':'account.email', 'email':element.value}, function(r){ 
           valid = parseInt(r.istaken) != 1 ? true : false;             
         },'GET');

         return valid;
      }
   }
});
```

/*Server returns: {"status":1,"istaken":0}*/ But input field verification : failed.
Where is a problem? Thanks.

Comment: Does `site.request` do the following: 1. `application/json` -> through `JSON.parse` so `r` is an object - else you may always be doing `NaN != 1 => true` or throw reference for `istaken`. if it's `0`/`1` returned and is object, you don't need to typecast it. just `valid = !!r.istaken;`; 2. run XHR with `async: false`, blocking the validator until a response has been reached? post the source of `site.request` and the value of the `app` object(?) that configures it etc - or at least give an overview

Answer (score 1):

Your request callback function (the function that processes the server response) is run asynchronously, but the validation function returns the value of "valid" (false) immediately.

When the callback function runs (i.e. after the server responds) the Form.Validator.add() function has already finished executing and the field has been marked as invalid long ago.